# How can I make my game character stop on the ground level

Tags: javascript, loops

I am struggling a bit with a piece of code. The point is that a "game character" should jump when the spacebar is pressed (to 100 px above floor-level) and fall down after. But in my case, the game character jumps once to the right height, falls to the ground and then jumps again and fly up to the sky, just to disappear. Each time I press the spacebar it comes back, just to jump another time to the sky. Cam someone just looks at my code and give me a hint of what I am doing wrong?

[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsqkW.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the community. Please edit your question and add code snippets instead of images to be easier for people to read and interract

Comment: One of your lines says `gameChar_y >= floorPos_y;`.  This line doesn't do anything. Also, please post your code as a snippet instead of an image, and include initial values (like floorPos_y etc).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isFalling == false){
  gameChar_y >= floorPos_Y;
}
```

It seems like the problem might be here. That's just a boolean expression and you're not modifying anything.